# How many parallel client socket i can create in my C# application?

Tags: c#, sockets, client

I am working on a A.I.D.C project where I need to Handle 21 fixed mount bar-code scanner and and 20 bar-code Printers and 1 P.L.C. I wanted to use client sockets to communicate with bar-code scanners and printers but i am not sure how many client socket i can create in one application and how it will affect the performance of the application? The printer and scanner are suppose to run 24/7. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 44 client sockets should be no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the memory of you computer generally.
[Maximum Number of Sockets Supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)